# use variables in batch script labels

Tags: batch-file, variables, label

I am able to use variables to reference a label, but I cannot seem to create a label with variables.

script that works ("worked" is successfully printed):

```
@echo off
set var=test
goto :label_%var%
echo did not work
pause
EXIT

:label_test
echo worked
pause
```

script that doesn't work (crashes when you run it):

```
@echo off
set var=test
goto :label_%var%
echo did not work
pause
EXIT

:label_%var%
echo worked
pause
```

Any suggestions on how to get `:label_%var%` to work?

Comment: You can't.  Variables are expanded when the line of the script is read. And then the line is executed.  The GOTO command starts from the top of the script looking for the label.  It is not expanding variables as it is trying to match the label name. So the label must already exist.  I can't think of any use case scenario as to why you would dynamically change the name of a label.  Even with functions in other scripting languages you would not want to do this.  You need to have a defined label or function name so you know what is going to execute.

Comment: In my actual script(s), `var` will be the version number of a program.  It can coincide with the version number of other programs referenced in the script, so doing a Ctrl+H to update the script for new versions isn't always feasible. Then again, those versions won't be referenced in any other labels, and I will ultimately be using multiple variations of `var` for each program, so Ctrl+H might be feasible for updating labels once I have the other variables in place. The use of a variable would still be slightly easier, though ;)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Escape the `%`s. In batch files `%`s are escaped by doing `%%`

```
@echo off
set var=test
goto :label_%%var%%
echo did not work
pause
EXIT

:label_%var%
echo worked
pause
```

Output

```
worked
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: This code is not doing what you think it is doing.  Neither of the `%var%` variables are expanding to `test`.  You are literally matching `label_%var%`.  Turn `ECHO ON` and watch all the commands execute or just comment out the `SET` command it will do exactly the same thing.  You are doing a literal match and not actually matching `label_test`.

Comment: @Squashman perhaps not, but I won't be actively viewing the script as it runs, so this still gives me what I'm looking for in terms of referencing (more or less).

Comment: @mathlete you are not understanding what the issue is with this code. This code literally matches the label `:label_%var%`.  It is not matching `label_test`.  Remove the `SET` command from the script and it will still echo `worked`!

Comment: @Squashman I understand that, but I think you are overlooking the fact that `var` ends up being used in other parts of my actual scripts (i.e. in practice, it's not being created for the sole purpose of creating labels).  I haven't had any issues using `var` in other parts of the real script yet - I was only having trouble working it into labels.  The fact that the variable isn't evaluating within labels does not hinder their functionality unless there's no way of working this unevaluated form in a `goto` call; Neko's answer shows how to do this, so it's a sensible solution to my problem.

Comment: @mathlete, the variable value is not being used in the GOTO or the LABEL.  So there is absolutely no reason to try and use it within the GOTO or the LABEL.

Comment: @Squashman true, but labels and `goto` calls never send data outside of the cmd window that the script is executing from (nor to do they read external data into the cmd window).  So, the fact that you can see the exact same characters while the script is running with echo on as you do when you edit the script (save for the extra `%` in the `goto` call) is nothing but a minor aesthetic issue.

Comment: @Squashman If you find it more prudent to use actual text instead of a variable, you can do it that way.  I personally wanted the labels to look more consistent with the rest of the script's use of this text, and Neko's answer accomplishes that goal.

Comment: If that's the case, then you may as well delete your question - all the end result you seek is to go to a label that matches the string "label_%var%", *not* a label that contains a dynamic variable, something there is no practical value to.

Comment: @Squashman I'm not sure what was intended, was matching `%var%` literally not intended? The OP didn't specify whether or not they were trying to match the label expanded or not, afaia concerned this solves the issue in the OP

Comment: @mathlete can you clarify whether or not you want the label to be expanded or just to be able to go to, this may clarify the argument in the comments of my answer and if this answer does satisfy your need, mark it as accepted (by clicking the checkmark)

Comment: @Squashman my coding is working as intended, it is going to the literal `label_%var%` label not the `label_test` label. I think you misunderstood what I was going for

Comment: @NekoMusume I ultimately won't be looking at the cmd window while the script runs, so seeing `%var%` expanded in the label is not strictly necessary (i.e. your first answer is a sufficient solution to my problem).  However, if there's a way to expand variables in a label, I would definitely be interested to know it.